# How to place a Rounded Rect UIBUTTON on UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I was trying to place two uibuttons on uitableviewcell programmatically.. but unable to achieve that>. somehow i managed to get the buttons through some sample project in which u can draw a nib for cell.. but i was unable to set a selector function for buttons.. in other example i can place a uiinfodark type button but when i change the type to rounded rect the button gets disappeared and i am unable to figure out why? I might be doing some silly mistake but I am really kinda stuck with it right now so I'll be very much thankful to all of you for helping in this regard.

Comment: you might want to post some sample code

Comment: You problem might be just a silly mistake. Unfortunately you haven't given us enough information to find it. Show us what you are doing and perhaps we can show you why you do not see the results you expected.

Comment: madmik3 and all others thanks for the replies.. though i was trying bit similar that you suggested madmik3 but it didn't work.. anyways i found out the solution in the uicatalog (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) for SDK4.2, modified it according to my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a UITableViewDataSource

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Then something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    // Get the object to display and set the value in the cell.
    [cell addSubView: YOUR_BUTTON];
    [cell addSubView: YOUR_OTHER_BUTTON];

   return cell;
}
```